# Documenting API model response model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm documenting an API and I'm wondering how to link the response format to the ViewModel I've created. The ViewModel has annotations which I want the user to browse. The problem being my controller returns *HttpResponseMessage* not the actual model itself, so the WebAPI help page skips over documenting this;

[image: API Help page]

In the HelpPageConfig.cs I've added the following;

```
config.SetSampleResponse(xmloutput.ToString(), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"), 
   "Course", "Get", new[] { "Id" });
```

How can I work around this, and create a link in the Help page using the APIExplorer. Or does this have to be done manually?

Example controller;

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)        {
   var obj = new Course(id);
   return this.Request.CreateResponse<Course>(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out how to do this, with the recently introduced [ResponseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Http.Description.ResponseTypeAttribute%29;k%28ResponseType%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) attribute;

```
 [HttpGet]
 [ResponseType(typeof(CourseModel))]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetById(string id)
 {
```